# Javascript Bookmarklet that writes Meta keywords into new (Browser) Tab

Tags: javascript, html, dom, bookmarklet

So i managed to get this working (script extracts site meta keywords and writes it into DOM)

```
javascript:(function metaKeywords() { metaCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); for (i=0;i<metaCollection.length;i++) { nameAttribute = metaCollection[i].name.search(/keywords/);if (nameAttribute!= -1) { document.write(metaCollection[i].content); } } } )();
```

and now I just need to figure out how to make the script write / open into a new browse tab

nearest script I could find for opening into new tab is this:

```
function openWindow( url ){window.open(url, '_blank');window.focus();}
```

but have no idea how to integrate the two. Please help!

Comment: P.S. no JQUERY please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function metaKeywords() {
    metaCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
    for (i = 0; i < metaCollection.length; i++) {
        nameAttribute = metaCollection[i].name.search(/keywords/);
        if (nameAttribute != -1) {
            var str = (metaCollection[i].content);
            window.open('javascript:document.write("' + str + '")');
            window.focus();
        }
    }   
})();
```

Or as a one liner:

```
javascript:(function metaKeywords() { metaCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); for (i = 0; i < metaCollection.length; i++) { nameAttribute = metaCollection[i].name.search(/keywords/); if (nameAttribute != -1) { var str = (metaCollection[i].content); window.open('javascript:document.write("' + str + '")'); window.focus();}}})();
```

You open up a new window (make sure it isn't blocked) and just set it to write the string into the contents. Jsfiddle won't allow document.write so I can't show you a demo, but it works on my machine(TM).